# How to detect if you move your finger inside ImageView

Tags: android, imageview, move, drag, slide

I've an ImageView in a LinearLayout, how can I detect when user drag his finger from any place in the screen to inside of ImageView?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Use OnFling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/937313/android-basic-gesture-detection)